# Gaming functions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get my objects to move in full motion in a `<canvas>` with things I do understand about javascript (although it's not much yet). I had to do a ton of research but I'm getting nowhere.

Im trying to get my game character, which is in the class of Player, to move. However, it isn't moving with my arrow keys. The console is receiving the logs from my function, but the character isn't moving.

JS dump:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('Game-Screen');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1200;
canvas.height = 900;
class Player {
  constructor(x, y, radius, speed, x_velocity, y_velocity, forward) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x_velocity = x_velocity;
    this.y_velocity = y_velocity;
    this.forward = forward = true;
  }
  Appear() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
};
controls = {
  right: false,
  left: false,
  up: false,
  keyEvent: function(pressed) {
    let keyCondition = (pressed.type == 'keydown') ? true : false;
    console.log(keyCondition);
    switch (pressed.keyCode) {
      case 37: //will go left
        controls.left = keyCondition;
        break;
      case 38: //will go up
        controls.up = keyCondition;
        break;
      case 39: // will go down
        controls.right = keyCondition;
        break;
    }
  }
};
const movement = function() {
  if (controls.up && Ship.forward == false) {
    Ship.y_velocity -= 20;
    Ship.forward = true;
  }
  if (controls.left) {
    Ship.x_velocity -= 0.5;
  }
  if (controls.right) {
    Ship.x_velocity += 0.5;
  }
  controls.y_velocity += 1.5;
  controls.x += controls.x_velocity;
  controls.y += controls.y_velocity;
  controls.x_velocity += 0.9;
  controls.y_velocity += 0.9;
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', controls.keyEvent);
window.addEventListener('keyup', controls.keyEvent);
const Ship = new Player(550, 800, 25, 0, 0);
const Astroids = [];
Ship.Appear();
function update() {
  this.x = this.x + this.x_velocity.x
  this.y = this.y + this.y_velocity.y
}
class Astroider {
  constructor(x, y, radius, speed, x_velocity, y_velocity, forward) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x_velocity = x_velocity;
    this.y_velocity = y_velocity;
    this.forward = forward = true;
  }
  Appear() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    //       x    y 
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
};
const Astro = new Astroider(600, 200, 40, 0, 0)
function spawnAstroids() {
  setInterval(() => {
    const x = 200
    const y = 300
    const radius = 40
    const color = 'grey';
    const velocity = {
      x: 1,
      y: 1
    }
    Astroid.push(new Astroider(x, y, radius, color, velocity))
  }, 2000)
  console.log(Astroid);
}
Astroid = [];
```

Comment: `(pressed.type == 'keydown')?true:false` can be shortened to `pressed.type === 'keydown'`

Comment: You never call `function movement()`; that might be a problem

Comment: I admit that this is somewhat irrelevant but isn't upper case naming conventionally reserved for classes?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow... you have a lot of code there! if the problem is just with the Player can you remove everything else and focus only on that, that help us all save time. _ _ _ You should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks thanks Rojo and Other me no it still works with my code although it may cause problems later on so Im changing it.